# Return a specific character in a string using conditional or error handling

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, error-handling, while-loop

Here's my problem:

I'm in a tutorial with edX in Python. The exercise asks me to:

**Write function called third_index that accepts a string as an argument and returns just the third character of the string. If the user inputs a string with fewer than 3 characters, return "too short".**

```
def third_index(myString):
    if len(myString) >= 3:
        for i in myString:
            count = 0
            while not count == 3:
                count =+ 1
            return i
    else:
        return "too short"  # Write your function here!

test1 = third_index("Hello World!")
print(test1)
```

When I try to run this, I get this result:
    H

My theory is that the loop is not functioning correctly. It stops at the first loop.

Thanks for the help, Experts! :)

Comment: Try changing the `for i in myString:` to `return myString [2]`. Strings have indexes, starting at zero. So the index 2 refer to the third position (0,1,2). And you call indexes like `something[index]`.

Comment: you code is wrong... in the for loop, when processing the first character, you just return. the while loop do nothing but add the count to 3.

Comment: THANK YOU GUYS! Helping me to be one of you. Hoping to catch up with you in the future.

Comment: Awesome guys! I got it now! Was trying to hard in incorporating all loops. I had a previous exercise which used "While loops" so I tried it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use array indexing on a string to get the third character. Just remember that the index of the first character is zero!

Here is some example code:

```
def third_index(myString):
    if len(myString)<3:
        print("Too short!")
    else:
        print(myString[2])

test1 = third_index("Hello World!")
```

Output:

```
l
```

Good luck, and welcome to the world of Python!

Answer (score 0):

Your function can be much more simpler:

```
def third_index(myString):
    if len(myString) < 3:
        return "too short"
    return myString[2]
```

Comment: myString[3] would actually return the _4th_ character! Be careful of this - strings are zero-indexed, same as any array-type

Comment: @DatHydroGuy, actually its true, quickanswering issues haha, thanks!

Comment: Awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With error handling:

```
def third_index(s):
   try:
       return s[2]
   except:
       return "too short"
```

With conditional:

```
def third_index(s):
   if len(s) < 3:
       return "too short"
   else:
       return s[2]
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Max!

Comment: Again, just be careful that in the first example, the line `return s[3]` would actually return the _4th_ character!

Comment: Fixed!  Can't believe I missed that!